# Shorten String between Chars until max char length is reached

Tags: java, string

in my GUI I'm displaying a path string via JLabel and a MouseListener opens the folder when clicked on the label. 
I want to shorten the displayed string between and after the first directory slashes until the whole string is under a certain length e.g. 20.

```
e.g.:
String regularPath="C:\Users\xy\Desktop\d1\d2\d3\d4\d5"; //->34 chars
String newPath=    "C:\...\d1\d2\d3\d4 " //->20 chars
```

I could't figure out a logic to implement this at the moment and I would appreciate your help (indexof("\\") always lead to an OutOfBoundsException). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try escaping the slash? Like `indexOf('\\')`

Comment: yes, just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a good candidate for a regex replacement using lookarounds.  You may find on the following pattern, and replace with ellipsis.

```
(?<=\w:\\).*?(?=.{0,14}$)

(?<=\w:\\)   assert that a drive letter pattern (e.g. C:\) precedes
.*?          match and consume everything until
(?=.{0,14}$) we see 14 more characters in the rest of the path
```

Note that the `.*?` quantity is what gets replaced with ellipsis, but everything on either side remains as is.  Also, paths which are shorter than 20 characters total will not match this pattern, and therefore will be printed in their entirety.

```
String regularPath = "C:\\Users\\xy\\Desktop\\d1\\d2\\d3\\d4\\d5";
regularPath = regularPath.replaceAll("(?<=\\w:\\\\).*?(?=.{14}$)", "...");
System.out.println(regularPath);

C:\...d1\d2\d3\d4\d5
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you very much this solves my use case. Nevertheless I still have to look at it closely to understand it completly.